# Protect Express API routes with Nuxt.js auth module

Tags: express, vue.js, jwt, nuxt.js, auth0

I'm still learning nuxt.js, so sorry if some config seems incorrect.

I enabled the `'@nuxtjs/auth-next',` module and set the `strategies:` to auth0.

Everything works correctly on the front-end and the routes are protected by the `middleware: 'auth'`

The problem is that I used the [Nuxt-Express template](https://github.com/nuxt-community/express-template) and I'm using Express for my API.

How can I safeguard my API routes in express and pass the Auth0 token to them?

The documentations are all over the place and there are very few tutorials on how Nuxt works with Express.